# how to generate different class types for provider automatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, auto-generate

Yes, I did check this: [image: Provider Docs]

And this: [Similar question answered on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052629/how-to-add-multiple-changenotifierprovider-in-same-type-in-flutter)

**But is there a way to auto generate different types?** cause I don't know how many of these classes a user may need.

Comment: what do mean by auto-generate, please give me an example.

Comment: Like for example, I can create a set of objects without provider with a loop which means I can **generate** objects depending on the requirement. But if it's a provider class,  different objects won't be differentiated by `ChangeNotifier` (as answered in the link above). How do I generate objects **Of Provider** such that ``Changenotifier`` can differentiate in the data from different objects?

Comment: Or if for such situations, provider isn't the right choice, what is?